# How to label string to IOB annotation using python?

Tags: python, nlp, data-annotations

I have a data-frame, with the start index and end index of the characters of the word/phrase that I need to label according to IOB annotation.

segments:

```
   start  end         keyword
0      4   10          voices
1     12   26  hallucinations
```

and a line :`Any voices, hallucinations ? [SEP] No.`

Sample output:

```
O B-seg B-seg O
```

Since this is an IOB tagging, the first word between the start and end index should be 'B-seg' and the other words in between should be 'I-seg'. All other words in the sentence should be 'O'. You can refer to the sample output above.

How do I do it in python?

Comment: @orde Hey, thanks for the reply. Yes, I'll go over it. :)